# NHibernate laziness concern

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, yield, lazy-evaluation

```
public IEnumerable<UserReadNews> GetLatestUserReadNews(IEnumerable<string> userIds)
{

    IQuery query = Session.CreateQuery("from UserReadNews as j where j.FacebookUser_id in (:userIds)");
    query.SetParameterList("userIds", userIds );
    return query.List();
}
```

I have this method where I want to return this data as lazily as possible, because I am determining which data to show and then stopping. I don't want the whole query to be executed against the whole table.

My concern is the List() method. is this lazy or eager?

Can I call this method from another method and `yield break` when I'm done with what I need?

Comment: Lazy loading works only on context of children entities and lookups. In your query if the result of query has 5 million rows, your code will still fetch one million rows, you'd rather put LIMIT clause or TOP clause there

Comment: There are two kinds of lazy loading, one occurs in ORM-database operation, which I mentioned above. And the other one is in the language, `ToList()` eagerly load elements to in-memory objects. I don't know if that `List()` eagerly load objects. Try to check the object type of the List returned object, if it is `List` or `List<classhere>`, it's eagerly loaded. If it is `IQueryable`, `IQueryable<classhere>`, `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<classhere>`, it's lazy loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @CSharper about only querying what you absolutely need.

If you still need to make this as lazy as possible after that optimization, use `ICriteria.Future<T>()` instead of `ICriteria.List<T>()`:

```
public IEnumerable<UserReadNews> GetLatestUserReadNews(IEnumerable<string> userIds)
{
    IQuery query = Session.CreateQuery("from UserReadNews as j where j.FacebookUser_id in (:userIds)");
    query.SetParameterList("userIds", userIds );
    return query.Future<UserReadNews>();
}
```

`Future` will give you an actual IEnumerable with deferred querying instead of a whole list right off the bat.  It will sometimes optimize queries too when given the chance.

Answer (score 1):

IQuery.List always returns the whole result set so early termination of the consuming loop with a yield break does not help getting more lazy.

The best thing is (if that's feasible in this case) to put your decision which items you really need from the result set already in the query so you don't cause effort in fetching not required data.